# From UML to C++ "Interface offered by a component"

Tags: c++, interface, uml, components

I'm reading a design document by this moment to implement the solution in C++.
In the legend, they explained a symbol by "Interface offered by a component".

I really don't get what they mean, and I'am unable to expect what would be a component in C++ and how could it "offer" an interface.

I hope I'm asking my question in the appropriate place. Thank you a lot in advance.

**Edit :** image added

[image: the interface]

Comment: By "component" it *might* mean a class, and by "interface" it *might* mean the public functions. However, for the real meaning you should ask the creator of the design document!

Comment: Can you post a picture of the relevant part of this UML diagram?

Comment: It suggests to me that the component extends a pure virtual class: all public pure virtual methods and a pure virtual destructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the UML "interface" symbol. Depending on context, it can mean a number of things:

- if the component is a library, the interface would be "an API" (i.e. a set of functions and/or classes that can be used to interface with the library functionality)
- if the component is a class, the interface should be  a public base class (or public abstract base class).

Comment: What about if the component is a "Module"?

Comment: C++ has no such thing as a module. When you find "module" in the context of C++, you can read that as "a logical grouping of code" (basically, a source/header file, a .dll/.a/.so file, a class, or a larger group of functionality (e.g. "the network connectivity module contains the http and ftp libraries").

Answer (score 0):

That lollipop notation represents a set of callable operations offered to a client. Most UML tools will allow you to switch to an alternative notation on the diagram, which would list those operations for you.